# how to use GSON to parse a class with INNER generic type?

Tags: generics, gson

i've googled gson and generic type, and all examples are about List < T >.

what if the generic type is inside a class? e.g.:

```
public class SAMPLE<T> {
    private int fixedHeader1;
    private String fixedHeader2;
    private List<T> data;
}
```

so how to use GSON to deserialize this class?

thx~

Comment: the json would be: {"fixedHeader1":"xxx", "fixedHeader2":"xxx", "data":[{}, {}, {}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be:

```
Sample<String> sampleWithStringListInside = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<Sample<String>>(){}.getType());
```

That is, it works just like deserializing generic`List`s (or other generic `Collection`s) with Gson. By setting the generic type of your `Sample` to `T` you also set the generic type of the contained `List` - that is all Gson needs to know.